# Why JavaStcript str.replace() doesn't work on long HTML strings?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I have long HTML file that I converted to a string using

`var str = fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', callBabk);`

Than I want to replace parts of the string with something else:

`str = str.replace('toReplace', 'replaceWithThis');`

But this doesn't work.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

The full code is:

```
exports.fileToString = function(path){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            return resolve(data);
        });
    });
};
```

Then in another file:

```
var htmlString = '';
Promise.all([
 htmlString = fileUtils.fileToString('../file.html'),
]).then(function() {
 htmlString = htmlString.replace('toReplace', 'replaceWithThis');
 console.log('htmlString: ' + htmlString); //This never prints
}. reject);
```

Comment: Add complete code. [mcve]

Comment: If you want to replace all occurrence of a text you need to use regular expression with `g` flag `/toReplace/g`

Comment: Also readFile don't return string, you get the string form inside a callback.

Answer (score 1):

`fs.readFile()` does not return the data that it read so your code:

```
var str = fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', callBabk);
```

is just completely wrong.  `fs.readFile()` is an async function and the result is ONLY available within the callback you pass it.

```
fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    var str;
    if (!err) {
        str = data.replace(/toReplace/g, 'replaceWithThis');
        // now do something with the modified string
    }
});
```

P.S. if you want to replace ALL occurrences of a given string (more than just the first match), you will also want the `g` flag on a regular expression.

Comment: @user3887119 - did this answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
// read the file
fs.readFile('./myfile.html', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
processContent(data)
});
//replace the strings
function processFile(content) {
    var str = content.replace(/toReplace/g, 'replaceWithThis');
    console.log(str);
}
```